# cant safe filtered for outputs to variable or compare them with if....==

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

i want to ask you if there is a way to use the ~n filter from the for loop.
here my example:

```
            for /d %%i in (%path%\*) do (
                set variable=%%~ni
            )
```

or

```
            for /d %%i in (%path%\*) do (
                if %%~ni==Pictures (
                       do something
                )
            )
```

i allways get the message that im using the filter in a wrong way.. 
maybe the solution is so obvious that i cant see it....
thanks for your help

Comment: Is there more to your code? What you have posted works perfectly. Also, what is the _exact_ message you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

i just found out that the problem for my problem wasnt my syntax or anything like that... i just had too many REM for documentation between the lines... thats kinda stupid..

but now ive got another problem.. :D
the code is

```
            set /a anzahlordner=0
            for /r %pfad%\ %%l in (.) do set /a anzahlordner=anzahlordner+1
            echo %anzahlordner%>>ftp.txt
```

thats my batch file, if i run it, the anzahlordner is always 0
BUT if i copy paste that code into cmd and let it run (with just %l) it counts correctly.. do you guys know what the problem here is?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

```
     setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

for everyone who had the same problems as me :)